# How to get name of an enum item in C++ CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, enums, c++-cli

Already I have the following code but the variable `System::String^ Name_` is `nullptr`:

```
enum EWeapons
{
    Fist    =   0   
}
System::String^ Name_ = Enum::GetName( EWeapons::typeid,0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use the `enum class` keyword to declare a managed enum type:

```
public enum class EWeapons
{
    Fist = 0   
};
...
System::String^ Name = Enum::GetName(EWeapons::typeid, (Object^)0);
```

Do beware a trouble-spot in later versions of Visual Studio (VS2012 and up), the C++11 language specification has adopted the `enum class` keyword as well.  Along with other C++/CLI keywords like `override` and `nullptr`.  That's a pretty nasty problem for `enum class`, the C++/CLI compiler does distinguish between native enums and managed enum types.  Managed enums end up in the metadata, native enums don't.  And of course Enum::GetName() cannot work for native enums.

You *must* use an accessibility keyword (`public` or `private`) to declare a managed enum type.  Not valid on native enums, the only way the compiler can tell the difference.

Comment: This certainly _should_ work, but it's not working for me with VC++ 2012 RTM. Even the `Enum::GetName` example on MSDN isn't working...

Comment: @ildjarn This should be counted as a bug. It's just MSDN example which doesn't work!!! (Used Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate)

Comment: @Mahdi : Actually I found the problem – `enum class` in VC++ 2012 creates a native scoped enum type (new to C++11) unless you specify an accessibility specifier. So, `enum class EWeapons` is a native type and won't work with `System::Enum`, but `public enum class EWeapons` and `private enum class EWeapons` will work as expected.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes that works now, Should you retag this to c++11 then ?; If you post this as your answer then I can accept it.

Comment: @Mahdi : The documentation for [`enum class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cskb49.aspx) indicates that the accessibility specifier is not optional, so this isn't really related to C++11, it was just invalid/incomplete C++/CLI syntax. With these comments taken into account, this answer is worth accepting IMO.

Comment: ***You must use an accessibility keyword (public or private) to declare a managed enum type.***

Thanks!